# Can I have cash back in a store or supermarket in Denmark as it's done in the States?

Tags: money, payment-cards, denmark

Can I walk in a grocery store in Denmark and after buying some stuff ask for withdraw cash by paying with credit card (i.e., as it's done in the US supermarkets)?

Comment: Purely as a general observation, this seem to generally NOT work with CREDIT cards, when overseas away from your home country.  (Indeed, as you know, within the US if you're from the US, quite often it is not available with credit cards, only debit cards.)  It's a good question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, not with a credit card. Some stores do offer cash withdrawals if you pay for a purchase by card, but usually (or perhaps even without exception) only if you pay with the national debit card 'Dankort'.

Comment: What about VISA debit cards?

Comment: @Fiksdal. As I already wrote: only if you pay with the national debit card 'Dankort'. Be aware though, that co-branded VISA/Dankort cards are available in Denmark and you can of course pay with these and withdraw cash. In that case you do however pay with the Dankort-functionality on the card.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it in most places cashback is only likely to be available with local debit cards.

Local Debit cards generally charge a flat fee per transaction so it's not a problem for the merchant to give cashback. Credit cards on the other hand usually charge a substantial percentage fee so merchants are unlikely to want to give cashback.

Debit cards aren't really standardised arround the world but the debit card issuers often work with a credit card network for international acceptance. So when you use your Debit card abroad it is likely to be treated as-if it was a credit card.